# Override resource engine

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm building an application in ASP.NET MVC 4. We have most of our text in resource files, but it's not 100% done.

In order to hunt down any remaining hard coded strings, I thought maybe I could just display any resourced string as gibberish characters (such as ***), and then we could visibly see what still needs to be converted.

So my question to you... Is there a way I could override the resource engine so instead of returning the requested string from a resource file, I would instead return my own value (***). Then I would be able to click through the app and see what strings are still hard coded in views.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. This is actually not very complicated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx

Or google for ASP.NET SQL Resource Provider. Would be interested in your solution, was thinking about the same too a few times.

Alternatively, most professional translation tools (e.g. Trados Studio) offer "Pseudo-Translations". That means they translate your text into exatly the gibberish you want. You could introduce another language and just this to test. This way you don't have to do any coding work.